# Time duration remaining unix timestamp

Tags: php, date

I have a `unix timestamp` and a duration, such as `a year`. I'd like to find out how to determine how much time is remaining from the duration based off the start unix timestamp. I want it in monthes.

I imagine its something like:

- duration convert to seconds.
- minus start to today to seconds (elapsed)
- minus elapsed from duration
- convert remaining to remaining in seconds
- change remaining to monthes and determine remainder to days

I'm sure thouhg theres a php solution which is more accurate and precise than my design i think.

UPDATE

I have a unix timestamp of `1564113711`, which is `July 26, 2019`. Today is `August 7,2019`. I need to know how much time remains in monthes and days from `July 26,2020` (one year from the start) to today, `August 7, 2019`, where the elapsed time is `July 26,2019 to August 7,2019`

Comment: Please provide sample inputs and corresponding desired results

Comment: You've not shown us what you've one nor explained why it does not meet your requirements. You say you want preceision, but to measure it in months then convert to days - but months are variable length (and so are days). You need to define the problem better before you have any chance of getting a solution.

Comment: updated question

Comment: PHP's `DateTimeInterval` class should provide what you need.

Comment: If the time difference is greater than a year, do you still only want months and days (26 months, 11 days)?  Or you would you want years, months, and days (2 years, 2 months, 11 days)?

Comment: @Barmar  You might be thinking of `DateInterval`.  There is no `DateTimeInterval`.  `DateTime::diff()` will probably also be useful here.

Comment: @PatrickQ if you can provide both that would be great.

Comment: @PatrickQ Yeah, that's it.

Comment: @Barmar Im not asking for free code advice. I understand the requirements, i just dont know how to do this in php using the native language. I will look at the DateTimeInterval object

Comment: @Barmar thanks the datetimeinterval object worked great.

Comment: You wrote "if you can provide both that would be great". If that's not asking for coding examples, what is it? Anyway, you're still supposed to post your coding attempt first, then we help you fix it.

Comment: @Barmar i understand my apologizes.

Comment: I think you have a problem with your definition of converting a duration to seconds. Thats because a duration like a month or a year has always a dynamical number of seconds! So keep in mind that a month could have 28,29,30,31 days! A year could have 365 or 366 days ... etc.

Answer (score 0):

The DateTime object and [DateTime::diff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) have everything you need.

```
$timeStamp = 1564113711; //26. Juli 2019
$duration = "1 Year";

$endDate = date_create("@".$timeStamp)->modify($duration);

$diff = date_create("today UTC")->diff($endDate);

//output
if($diff->invert) {
  echo "your time's up";
}
else {
  echo $diff->y * 12 + $diff->m." Month and ".$diff->d. " Days";
  //e.g. 10 Month and 24 Days
}
```